# Display Mitmproxy's Events Log on Linux

Tags: linux, logging, command-line-interface, mitmproxy

[Mimtproxy docs](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-options/) only talks about how to increase events log *verbosity*, and on  Linux I can't seem to find the mentioned log file either in ***~/.mitmproxy*** nor in the standard ***/var/log*** folders.

Is there a way to access the mitmproxy's event log file ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Okey finally I just found out the solution myself ...
From the mitmproxy console, type `:console.view.eventlog`

Turned out to be pretty easy, but I still think that such information should have been provided either on linux manual pages of mitmproxy or on its docs website, by the way.

Comment: I have the same question regarding the mitmdump command line tool, which is not interactive, so the answers given here don't seem to apply.   The docs indicate you can turn on and set verbosity for mitmdump, but like you, I surprisingly cannot locate any documentation of *where* logs would be found.

Comment: @M.Bearden try to use ` --save-stream-file log.txt` option. It should save logs to this file when you will stop proxy.

Answer (score 32):

The eventlog can be viewed by pressing `E` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) when in mitmproxy.

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut, faster solution for me.

Comment: Shift+E did it for me. When I tried E by itself, I just kept seeing some weird thin white pipes at the bottom of the terminal.